# Why is the program crashing when the button is being clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom cell with a button, and I am trying to add an action to it. For some reason the app crashes with the error `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. How do I fix this? My syntax seems correct.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("searchcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! searchcustomcell

 //follow is the name of the button in the custom cell
       cell.follow.addTarget(self, action: "FollowUser:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)


    func FollowUser(sender: UIButton){
        var relation: PFRelation = (PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("Friendship"))!
        relation.addObject(users[indexPath.row])

 return cell
    }
```

Comment: Which selector and which class of instance?  (It's better to paste the entire error message into your question rather than trying to describe it.)

Comment: http://puu.sh/l7awG/7eeebf1813.png

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason the app crashes with the error unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Not "for some reason". That *is* the reason. You are sending an unrecognized selector to an instance. The problem is that your `FollowUser` function is not a method; it is hidden inside your `collectionView:cellForItem...` method. Cut it, and paste it at the top level of your class:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // ...
}
func FollowUser(sender: UIButton){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need to access the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in the FollowUser function. Your method does not allow that. Is there anyway to avoid this error, and have FollowUser function have access to `cellForItemAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I have answered the question you asked. If you do what I said to do, you will not crash. Problem solved. If that gives rise to a new question, ask a new question, but you _must_ make the change I said to make or you will just on crashing.